# Freemarker Help: Pass Data to List Directive for Sorting

Tags: freemarker

First time poster and a Freemarker novice.  I'm hoping someone can assist on this.  I am currently referencing data from a 1-to-many table using the `<#data>` directive.  I want to sort the results in a particular field order, but I think that can only be done by the `<#list>` directive. Here's what I have so far:

There's a CART_ABANDONMENT table with the following fields:

CUSTOMER_ID_
PRODUCT_ID
PRODUCT_NAME
PRODUCT_PRICE
ABANDONED_DATE

```
<#data CART_ABANDONMENT as abandonment><br>
<#filter CUST_ID="${CONTACTS_LIST.CUSTOMER_ID_}"><br>
<#fields PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME PRODUCT_PRICE ABANDONED_DATE><br>
${abandonment.PRODUCT_NAME} ${abandonment.PRODUCT_PRICE}<br>
</#data>
```

What I want to do is to list all related results (by CUSTOMER_ID_) and sort them by PRODUCT_PRICE, descending.

It may be something simple, but I haven't been able to find the answer.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like FreeMarker... there's no `#data`, `#field` etc. there.

Answer (score 1):

Freemarker is powerful tool tool but it's just template engine.

It has the [sort directive](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_sort) for list, but it can be applied only to built-in types: String, Number and Date.

You may convert list of you complex type to one or more lists of built-in types and use `?sort` in template.

Another way is to pass already sorted(as you want) list to template before processing.

Answer (score 0):

What you want sounds like something that should be solved on the database (SQL) level, especially where you say "list all related results (by CUSTOMER_ID_)". FreeMarker is only the V (for View) in MVC.